# How to remove a single associated Schema from Workflow?

Tags: publishing, web8.5, workflow

I'm attempting to remove Workflow from an instance of SDL Web Cloud. Unfortunately, Workflow has only been configured on the Staging/Live environment which limit what I can do.

As a test, I've selected one Schema and unticked the "Any changes made to a Component based on this Schema require approval by a Bundle Workflow Process" which removed the Schema from the Workflow Process Association.

I republished a page with an edited content to the appropriate Target Types. The change reflects fine on the Staging Purpose but Live still has stale data.

Upon further investigation, I found that the Live Purpose has a "Minimal Approval Status" of a custom "Default_Live" which is set from the last step of the current Workflow associated with a Bundle.

Next, I updated the "Minimal Approval Status" to the default "(None)" and once again republished the page in question. The theory will be that the updated content will reflect to Live Purpose.

The latest content is still not reflecting on Live. To ensure it's not cache-related I waited 1 hour and also queried the Content Service through Postman:

`https://example-company-production.tridion.sdlproducts.com:8084/client/v2/content.svc/Pages(ItemId=161819,PublicationId=19)/PageContent`

The results shows the old content which suggests that it's not caching but publishing.

I wanted to clarify my understanding and hope someone could help:

Is my approach correct/feasible or is there a standard way of doing this?

If so, if a Page contains other Components that are associated to Workflow, will the Page require to go through Workflow first or will it attempt to publish your update (not Workflow associated) content and leave the other Components to use the last approved version?

If there's anything else I can add, please let me know.

Comment: "The latest content is still not reflecting on Live" - are you certain the content is checked in and not in any minor version of workflow?

Comment: The content is checked in and not in any minor version of workflow.

Comment: Note that the Minimal Approval Status is only used to determine whether the _dynamic version_ of items in workflow qualifies for publishing. If not, the latest checked-in version will be published (and if that one doesn’t meet the Minimal Approval Status, an error is generated, IIRC). So, it is hard to imagine that an old version gets published. Can you inspect the tranport package to verify what is being published, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Your above approach for disabling workflow is 'probably' correct, based on the type of workflow you have implemented. There is no recommended way to remove workflow. You will have to look into your design documents to actually determine the detailed steps involved in the implementation, so that you can disable it.

In general, SDL will republish your update on the page with the other components in the last approved version, unless you have enabled workflow in your Structure Group containing the page as well.

Since your page is successfully published to staging (manually) without issues, I would assume that the content is checked in and no minor version are being used.

I would look at the broker database directly to make sure that the items are being updated correctly. If the content is available in the broker, publishing (your custom code  like TBBs, event system, custom renderer / resolver, etc) is NOT an issue.

If the content is NOT available in the broker, you need to disable your custom modules to narrow down on the issue. Hope it helps!